# Is it possible to fix rounding issues when pixelizing UV coordinates?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm working on a blocky voxel game. I implemented smooth shading from the [0fps](https://0fps.net/2013/07/03/ambient-occlusion-for-minecraft-like-worlds/) article, and it worked great.

[image]

Today I decided I wanted to make it less-smooth by pixelizing it. Each of the vertices that make up the triangle strip (the quad) have a `vec4 shadows`. And I just bilinearly interpolate between those 4 shadow points using the UV coordinates that would otherwise be for a texture..

```
float pixelize(float x) { return floor(x*BLOCK_DIMENSION) / BLOCK_DIMENSION; }
float linear(float u, float a, float b) { return a + u*(b - a); }
float bilinear()
{
    float v0 = linear(pixelize(texUV.x), shadows.x, shadows.y);
    float v1 = linear(pixelize(texUV.x), shadows.z, shadows.w);
    return linear(pixelize(texUV.y), v0, v1);
}
```

But no matter how much I try to fudge it (adding 0.125f or 0.5f or whatever), I can't get it perfect. The pixelization is shifted by 1 (notice there's 4 shades on the left side, and 3 shades on the right side); the shading isn't symmetric.
[image]

Is it possible to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `0.5` to the result of `floor`, like so:

```
float pixelize(float x) { return (floor(x*BLOCK_DIMENSION) + 0.5) / BLOCK_DIMENSION; }
```

I bet you tried to add it somewhere else, which is not the same.

The motivation for this can be understood using the following diagram:

[image]

The sampling of the second row is asymmetrical within the interval because `floor` shifts everything down. Adding `0.5` restores that symmetry.

Comment: Wow; all this time I was putting it in `return floor(x*BLOCK_DIMENSION + 0.5f) / BLOCK_DIMENSION;` and not thinking twice about it. Thank you so much!